# Flutter web json data not getit

Tags: json, flutter, rest, web, flutter-web

i am new to flutter web but this error is crazy my func to get json data is

```
@override
  Future<List<StoryEntity>> getNewAnimation(int id) async{
    print("ali");
    return (json.decode(
        (await http.Client().get(Uri.parse('https://hekayatname.ir/home/getanimation')))
            .body)['list'] as List)
        .map(
          (e) => StoryEntity(
        title: e['fullname'],
        imagePath: e['logo_url'],
        description: "e['description']",
        rating: 1,
        galleryImagesPath: [],
        id: e['id'],
        producer: e['address'],
      ),
    ).toList();
  }
```

but i recive nothing in flutter.
in web browser my data is like this just go to this link
https://hekayatname.ir/home/getanimation
i change the code to this

```
  Future<List<StoryEntity>> getNewAnimation(int id) async{
    print("1");
    final response = await http.Client().get(Uri.parse("https://hekayatname.ir/home/getaudioestory"));
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      print("2");
    }
    else{
      print("3");
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
}
```

i have nothing to both if and else
if not work,else not work.... need help!!

Answer (score 0):

[Visit this link](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/). Copy your json response and paste in the json section. Give your class name and hit Generate Dart.
[image]

Now hit copy dart code and add it your project. Then you can use it like inside the success case.

**Note** if you face any error of `Null` object. Thats mean your response contains null values and replace this data type with the corresponding data type.

```
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      print('2');
      YourJsonResponse obj = YourJsonResponse.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else{
      print("3");
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
```